# How do I detect tcp-client disconnect with gen_tcp?

Tags: tcp, erlang

I'am trying to use gen_tcp module.
There is example of server-side code, which I have troubles.

```
%% First, I bind server port and wait for peer connection
{ok, Sock} = gen_tcp:listen(7890, [{active, false}]),
{ok, Peer} = gen_tcp:accept(Sock),

%% Here client calls `gen_tcp:close/1` on socket and goes away.
%% After that I am tryin' send some message to client
SendResult = gen_server:send(Peer, <<"HELLO">>),

%% Now I guess that send is failed with {error, closed}, but...
ok = SendResult.
```

When I call `gen_tcp:send/2` again, second call wil return `{error, closed}` as expected. But I want to understand, why first call succeeded? Am I missing some tcp-specific details?
This strange (for me) behavior is only for {active, false} connection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In short, the reason for this is that there's no activity on the socket that can determine that the other end has closed. The first `send` appears to work because it operates on a socket that, for all intents and purposes, appears to be connected and operational. But that write activity determines that the other end is closed, which is why the second `send` fails as expected.

If you were to first read or `recv` from the socket, you'd quickly learn the other end was closed. Alternatively, if the socket were in an Erlang `active` mode, then you'd also learn of the other end closing because `active` modes poll the socket.

Aside from whether the socket is in an `active` mode or not, this has nothing to do with Erlang. If you were to write C code directly to the sockets API, for example, you'd see the same behavior.